# Can update the HASH key to another attribute for a pre-existing Dynamodb global secondary index?

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

Having an existing GSI with key (HASH: user, RANGE: date), can I update the key to (HASH: group, RANGE: date) without creating a new index?

The `group` attribute is an existed attribute i table and also projected into the GSI already.

Answer (score 1):

No, DynamoDB does not support changing the HASH and RANGE values for tables or indexes, if you need them changed you will have to create a new GSI with the desired values and remove the old one.

**Extra:** If you hav't already i would highly suggest watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k) about DynamoDB design patterns it might provide useful insight that may help up down the line.